# domPDF inline PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am working on creating a PHP script to convert my HTML/CSS/PHP pages into a PDF. I have come across the class domPDF and I have uploaded all files to my server. I am trying to wrap my head around this and I have wrote this sample script to see if I could get it to work. The script is:

```
ob_start() ;

require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$file= file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com');

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html_file($file);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

And I am getting this error:

> `"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Permission denied on <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en-US" class="y-fp-bg y-fp-pg-grad bkt701" style=""> <!-- m2 template --> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <title>Yahoo!</title> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1"> <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Yahoo!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and information."> <meta name="keywords" content="yahoo, yahoo home page, yahoo homepage, yahoo search, yahoo mail, yahoo messenger, yahoo games, news, finance, sport, entertainment"> <script type="text/javascript"> //Roundtrip rtTop = Number(new Date()); document.documentElement.className += ' jsenabled'; </script> <script type="text/javascript"> (function () { //refresh check var d=document,c=";\ in /home/public_html/Sandbox/include/dompdf.cls.php on line 329"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use:

```
$dompdf->load_html($file);
```

rather than

```
$dompdf->load_html_file($file);
```

Comment: this got me working but now its throwing out "value data" instead of the actual content. any thoughts on that?

Comment: @GeraldoIsaaks it sounds like you're at a different step (this just covers loading in the DOM structure - I'm guessing that you're trying to grab some specific data or node). You should post your code and question as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with domPDF, but judging by the error message and the function's name, I assume `load_html_file()` expects a *filename* but you're giving it the *contents* of a HTML file. Try `$dompdf->load_html_file( 'http://www.yahoo.com' )` or find a function that accepts a HTML string as a parameter.